# What's the purpose of this weird capitalize function?

Tags: javascript, case-sensitive

I'm looking through the code for kibo.js and found this function:

```
Kibo.capitalize = function(string) {
  return string.toLowerCase().replace(/^./, function(match) { return match.toUpperCase(); });
};
```

Anyone have any ideas why they might use this instead of just .toUpperCase?

PS - Kibo is found at https://github.com/marquete/kibo/blob/master/kibo.js

Comment: Is there some reason you couldn't just [test it yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/3xs9A/1/)?

Comment: I didn't do a good job explaining the question... I guess the way I would've done it is without a regular expression, and toUpperCase on the first character, combined with toLowerCase on the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically converts the entire string to lower case first, and then capitalizes just the first letter.

`capitalize:`

```
TEST => Test
test => Test
teST => Test
```

...as opposed to `toUpperCase:`

```
test => TEST
teST => TEST
Test => TEST
```

`toLowerCase:`

```
TeST => test
TEST => test
tesT => test
```

Some languages also have a `titleize` method which capitalizes the first letter of each word, as in a title/proper name:

```
mary poppins          => Mary Poppins
a lovely and talented => A Lovely and Talented Title
what a title!         => What a Title!
the meaning of life   => The Meaning of Life
hello, world!         => Hello, World!
```

Notice that it **doesn't** capitalize "and", "of", "the", etc. unless they are the first word in the string.

Answer (score 1):

`toUpperCase`  converts all letters to upper case letters. This function, `Kibo.capitalize`, first converts all letters to lower case and then converts only the first letter (`/^./`) of the string to an upper case letter.

```
Kibo.capitalize('hello') // returns 'Hello'
'hello'.toUpperCase() // returns 'HELLO'
```

Answer (score 1):

The function, well, capitalizes the string, i.e. turning the first letter to upper case and the following letters — to lowercase.

```
console.log(Kibo.capitalize('alEx'));

/*
 * Outputs:
 * 'Alex'
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> capitalize("hi mom")
"Hi mom"
>>> capitalize("HI MOM")
"Hi mom"
>>> capitalize("Hi Mom")
"Hi mom"
```